# Pixel+Cookie Conversion Tracking From Tracker's Point of View

Tags: php, cookies, tracking

Just trying to make a conversion tracking system (pixel+cookie) with PHP for study purpose. Just need some ideas and guides regarding this from tracker point of view.

I have basic understanding on how it works. Basically there are 4 parties involved: merchant, tracker, promoter and user. Merchant places iframe based pixel (from tracker) on their thank you (last check out) page.

1. User surfs the web, finds an ad/offer and clicks
2. It directs to tracker. Then tracker puts cookie on user's computer and redirects to merchant's landing page
3. User likes the product during this first visit. He/she adds to cart, checkouts and make a payment. Thank you page shows up and fires the pixel.
4. Tracker get necessary parameters and checks for cookie in user's computer, records the sales and gives credit to the promoter.

Well, all this works if there is only one tracker, merchant, promoter.

## My questions are:

(a) How to correctly identify sales when multiple parties are involved? 
(b) Also user may not buy the product on the same day. Instead he/she might come back directly and buy the product after a week or two.

## (a) Scenario

M- Merchant
T1,T2,T3 - trackers (supposing we are T1)
U - user

In this case merchant may join force with all three trackers and put pixel from each on their thank you page.

1. User may have landed on particular merchants page from all the tracker links including us. In this case user's computer contains all three cookies from three different trackers.
2. When user buys the product and reaches Thank you page pixel will fire up for all three tracker. Each tracker will check for cookie and finds their cookie present and might confirm sales.

In this case, there is a possibility of 3 recorded sales where in fact is just one sale.

So the question is how each tracker will know, whether this sales is theirs or not and avoid that as they cannot access cookies of other trackers?

## (b) Scenario

Same goes for after click tracking.

Supposing cookie duration is 30 days. (i) User buys product after 15 days after clicking the ad. (ii) Multiple cookie must have already been present in user's computer.

So from particular tracker's point of view, how do we identify the sale correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it depends on what you mean by "tracker." A tracker usually is a 3rd party affiliate network that uses a tracking solution. They pair up a merchant (who is selling the product) with a publisher (who advertises and displays the link).

**So to answer to question A:**

I think it would be unlikely for a merchant to have 3 different "trackers" sending them visitors. Typically, if you were the merchant, you sign up with one affiliate network, then recruit publishers within that network. It wouldn't be smart to sign up with more than one, probably for this very reason.

If more than one cookie was set (within the one affiliate network), the affiliate network would typically use the rule of "last cookie," which means the last ad that was clicked before the purchase is the one that the sale goes to.

Take a look at this similar Quora question: http://www.quora.com/Should-merchants-use-multiple-affiliate-networks-to-sell-their-product-Why-or-why-not

**In answer to Question B:**

If cookie duration is 30 days, and a user comes back in 15, there should be no problem. If the buyer goes directly to the merchant's site, buys the product, and see's the "thank you" page where the tracking pixel (or whatever tracking solution they use) is, that pixel will fire. The pixel calls a server-side script, like PHP, that will test whether the user has the particular cookie. So it doesn't matter whether the user comes back directly, or when they come back to buy the product. As long as they still have that cookie (within the 30 day limit), the sale will be registered.

Comment: Hi Kev, thanks for clarifying that and pointing to the article. Yes my tracker I am viewing from the affiliate network side (not the merchant).

Comment: So my suspicion is true that merchant may end up paying multiple affiliates for single transaction. But in real world, I have seen merchants promoting through multiple affiliate networks. In that case I guess they have to use some kind of conditional pixel firing method. I wonder how they implement that. Can you point me to  any kind of documentation on this? At least its clear that this is not the problem from affiliate network tracking point of view. Its Merchant's problem.

Comment: I wonder if popular shopping cart packages (like Magneto, opencart etc.) have this conditional pixel firing implemented properly.  Thanks again!